# how to determine order and count of arguments in getopt

Tags: c, macos, arguments

I use getopt to get arguments from terminal, but it depends me on the order of arguemts. there's a difference between

```
./my -A -B -C
```

and

```
./my -B -A -C
```

is there any way to determine the order?
secondly, I'd like to determine count of the args (if there are some optional ones)

ps sorry for my english, i hope you understand what i mean

Answer (score 0):

You record the order in which `getopt()` returns them.  It returns them in left-to-right order, so there's no mystery.  In the first invocation, `-A` is reported before `-B` and `-C` is reported last.  In the second, `-B` is reported before `-A` and `-C` is still last.  You can decide to do the processing when the arguments are read (so the actions occur while you're reading the options), or you can store the options in the sequence they appear and do the processing after the options are completely read.  Both are feasible.  If an error occurs with the first technique, though, the early processing will have been done.  If that's unacceptable, process all the options first.

You can count the number of option arguments in your loop easily enough:

```
int optcnt = 0;
int opt;
while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "ABC")) != -1)
    optcnt++;
```

You'd have a loop within braces with a switch as well as the simple increment, probably.

Note that you can have repeated options, possibly with a different option value on each time:

```
./my -D name1 -D name2 -A -B -D name3 -C
```

You can keep a record of which options and which names appear in sequence.

```
int optcnt = 0;
int opt;
int o_idx = 0;
int d_idx = 0;
char *d_opts[20];
char  o_opts[20];

while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "ABCD:")) == -1)
{
    optcnt++;
    switch (opt)
    {
    case 'A':
    case 'B':
    case 'C':
        o_opts[o_idx++] = opt;
        break;
    case 'D':
        o_opts[o_idx++] = opt;
        d_opts[d_idx++] = optarg;
        break;
    default:
        …report error and exit…
        break;
    }
}

/* Parsing complete - do final checks */

/* Processing loop */
int d = 0;
int i;
for (i = 0; i < o_idx; i++)
{
    switch (o_opts[i])
    {
    case 'A':
        process_A();
        break;
    case 'B':
        process_B();
        break;
    case 'C':
        process_C();
        break;
    case 'D':
        process_D(d_opts[d++]);
        break;
    }
}
assert(d == d_idx && i == o_idx);
```

Resetting `getopt()` back to the beginning is an undocumented art; try not to need to reparse your command line.

Answer (score 0):

you have argv[] as a parameter passed to main()  it contains an array of pointers to character strings.  Those strings are in the exact order they were on the command line.  The way to determine if some argument was listed before another.
is to step through the argv[] strings.